# Live USB boot does not work "any more!

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

For the past couple of days I was experimenting with Ubuntu. 
I am running Ubuntu 14 (BIOS) on a Dell xps 15Z.
I used a USB drive to install ubuntu on this system (HP formatting tool & YUMI) however since a failed a try in installing WIN 7 OEM via usb, this system does not boot with live USB anymore: " Operating system not found."

I tried to remake the usb via another laptop running windows, the usb works on that laptop but not on the this one running ubuntu; Then I made a live usb using "Startup Disk Creator", which still does not work on this laptop.

Any ideas what is the cause and how I can fix it?

p.s: I do not have CD/DVD drive on this laptop.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like Your BIOS settings are not set to boot from USB stick (`Boot from other devices`). Anyway I would try pressing F12 after power on (F12 is common key for `Boot menu`) and pointing at Your USB drive (must be shown there to be booted). Because `Operating system not found.` rather says about HDD not the USB.

Comment: USB is the first device for booting, I have not changed that. The HDD is working fine, I have a ubuntu installed as I said which is working.

Comment: So USB works for other comp but not with the installed & working Ubuntu? And nothing wrong in BIOS? Must be matrix error. Or compatibility of USB's boot sector.

Comment: Dell xps15z bios is limited, you can only do basic stuff such as changing the boot sequence or enabling/disabling external usb - not changing the boot type. The bios setting have not changed since the last successful boot via usb. 
So, how can I make sure the usb's boot sector is compatible with this system as well? I tried to make a usb boot from the ubuntu, which fails to work on this system, but boots up my other laptop!

Comment: And You can not choose the boot device for a single time? Otherwise that could point out if Your USB informs about boot option. On the internet I've found a case related to me a while ago `"Access to the BIOS, and change disk support from UEFI to LEGACY , and then your USB-stick will be recognized"`.

Comment: unfortunately, Dell XPS15Z does not let you change between UEFI/Legacy

Comment: This is mad. I'm always booting USB with `wingrb` installed which allows to have menu and add more options (e.g. .iso) just by copying files and changing the menu file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same USB you used to install Windows with to try and boot Ubuntu Live CD are you sure you formatted it before burning the ISO on it?

Comment: I first made the usb on another windows running machine, using YUMI multiboot creator, I had bootrepair, ubuntu, windows and couple of other tools on the usb.

on the second and third time I made a live usb on windows and on Ubuntu, I formatted it using HP Formatting tool and Startup Disk creator respectively. Anyway, as I said, the usb is working fine on another laptop while booting. It is only this system running ubuntu which can not use the usb as a boot anymore.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood that.

Comment: You didn't change anything BIOS?

Comment: It's the "Operating system not found." line that makes me think it's related to the way you setup the USB.  I had a similar error when I was booting a Mac using a Windows 7 USB.  And as it turns out the problem was I had put some data on the USB in a directory after creating the bootable USB.  And somehow that simple thing confused the boot process.

Comment: Yeah if BIOS settings are correct then USB drive is not - but then it should NOT work on other comp. Keep in mind that Ubuntu does not affect booting up (that early in boot, it is).

Comment: you can change basically nothing in Dell XPS15Z bios, unless you have hacked that, which I did not. Might be that I have to copy something on USB now - but before I did not need to do anything extra, and still the usb works as a "boot" on another system I have, and I am able to copy and paste files on it when I am on this laptop using ubuntu.

Comment: Are You certain You can not change or lookup BIOS settings? For example in my HP 655 I have to press Esc first instead of anything else.

Comment: This has got me totally stumped then.  You shouldn't have to add anything to the USB after making it bootable and putting the ISO on it. You should check to make sure (it's a long shot) but that the USB port is compatible with the USB stick.  Try a different port with it.  USB 3.0 vs USB 2.0

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I have already checked the bios as well. Everything is as it should to be. And as I said you can not change the EFI/UEFI/BOOT on XPS 15Z laptop bios. so that one is also out of question. It is reading the usb drive, however, it is not booting from it, shows "operating system not found." - upon removing the usb and restarting the system, it loads ubuntu.

@daniel: I have used both parts on the laptop, still the same error. As I said, for past couple of days I was able to use the USB boot but not anymore ....

Comment: And if that doesn't work, the last thing I know is that when I'm booting from a USB on my computer, I'm given two options for the usb at boot.  One is UEFI and the other I guess is legacy I'm not very familiar with either but all I know is that if one option doesn't work I try the other and it'll work.

Comment: unfortunately, Dell XPS15Z does not let you change between UEFI/Legacy